# How should we chain the work request with the input data in android work manager?

Tags: android, android-workmanager

*I am trying to learn work manager chaining with passing output of one to another*

Here are my objectives,

1. I have two work request WR1 (gets me the url) and WR2 (sends request to the url)
2. I can't and should not start the WR2 until the WR1 completes.
3. WR1 is supposed to return a url to which i have to send to WR2 as inputData
4. I can mostly do this without chaining. But i would to like explore it in the chaining.

Here is my snippet in progress. **Please help**.

```
WorkManager mWorkManager = WorkManager.getInstance(this);

//WR1
OneTimeWorkRequest urlRequest = new 
OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(UriResolveWorker.class).build();

//WR2
OneTimeWorkRequest pullRequest = new 
OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(PullReplicator.class).build();

btnStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mWorkManager.beginWith(urlRequest)
                             .then(pullRequest) // I should be able to pass the result of urlRequest. 
                             .enqueue();
            }
        });

mWorkManager.getWorkInfoByIdLiveData(urlRequest.getId()).observe(this, new 
Observer<WorkInfo>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(WorkInfo workInfo) {
                if (workInfo != null) {
                    WorkInfo.State state = workInfo.getState();
 
                    // I will get the URL here and i want to pass this to WR2

                    message = workInfo.getOutputData().getString("work_result");
                    tvStatus.append("\n"+"state : "+state.toString() + "message : " +message + "\n");
                    }
                }
        });

        mWorkManager.getWorkInfoByIdLiveData(pullRequest.getId()).observe(this, new Observer<WorkInfo>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(WorkInfo workInfo) {
                if (workInfo != null) {
                    WorkInfo.State state = workInfo.getState();
                    String count = workInfo.getOutputData().getString("work_result");
                    tvStatus.append("\n"+"state : "+state.toString() + " No of Documents : " +count + "\n");o 
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

Before returning the **Result** object in **doWork()** method of **UriResolveWorker** class, You can pass the url to Result.success().

First create object of **Data.Builder()** and then put the url into:

```
Data.Builder outputDataBuilder = Data.Builder();
outputDataBuilder.putString(KEY_URL_STRING, url.toString());
```

after that, create Data object with outputDataBuilder:

```
Data outputData = outputDataBuilder.build();
```

now you can return the **Result** with **outputData** :

```
return Result.success(outputData);
```

---

**Workmanager** sends the data to **pullRequest** when the first one has been done.

Please check the **state** of the WorkRequest before getting the data.
For example:

```
private final Observer<WorkInfo> urlWorkInfo = workInfo -> {

    if (workInfo == null) {
        return;
    }

    WorkInfo.State state = workInfo.getState();
    if (state.isFinished()) {

        String url = workInfo.getOutputData()
                  .getString(KEY_URL)

        if (url != null) {
            Log.d(TAG_MAIN_ACTIVITY, url);
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG_MAIN_ACTIVITY, "Url not found!");
        }

    } else if (state == WorkInfo.State.RUNNING) {
        Log.d(TAG_MAIN_ACTIVITY, "Associated WorkRequest is being executed");

    }
};
```

Comment: Thank you Sir. But i did the same. I returned Result.success(url) but the second worker already enqued and it does not consider the url that i sent. But if i dont chain, it will work.

Comment: Do you have any exceptions? I tested a similar condition, and it worked. Please make sure that the **state** is finished by calling isFinished() method before you call getOutputData(); otherwise, It returns an empty data and the **message** will be null.

Comment: oh. i didn't do that part. do you have small snippet of the same?

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been a while since you asked this question, but maybe it might help someone in the feature:

In WR1 (Worker 1) you will have output with specific key - data that you want in your second worker (WR2):

```
Result.success(workDataOf(MY_TEST_KEY to someData.toString()))
```

Now if you want to get that data in WR2 you cannot send it trough **setInputData()** method when creating your **OneTimeWorkRequest** and chaining it.

As everything is forwarded from WR1 to WR2, in WR2 you have to fetch that data like:

```
inputData.getString(WR1.MY_TEST_KEY)
```

And than use it as you want in your WR2.

Hopefully this will help someone in the future, official documentation can be found here: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/how-to/chain-work